# Возникает ошибка при деструкции потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Есть класс и 2е функции:

```
class TaskList {
public:
    std::list<std::pair<BYTE, std::vector<BYTE>*>> list;
    std::mutex listMutex;

    void Push(std::vector<BYTE>* block){
                
                listMutex.lock();
                list.push_back(std::make_pair(0, block));
                listMutex.unlock();

                if (!isRun) algothread = new std::thread(StartAlgos, &isRun, &list, this); 
   }
}

void StartAlgos(bool* isRun, std::list<std::pair<BYTE, std::vector<BYTE>*>>* list, TaskList* tl){

        // Set current state
        *isRun = true;

        // While we can make Push, we should check list
        while (list->size()){

            // Go through list and start algos
            tl->listMutex.lock();
            for(auto& listitem : (*list)){
                if (!listitem.first) {
                    listitem.first = 1;
                    tl->threadList.emplace_back(std::thread(StartAlgoThread, &(listitem), tl));
                }
            }
            tl->listMutex.unlock();

            // Wait for first task to write
            if (tl->threadList.front().joinable()) tl->threadList.front().join(); // 0 - StartAlgo's thread

            //  Write prepared blocks
            hu deleteCount = 0;
            tl->listMutex.lock();
            while (!list->empty() && list->front().first == 2){

                // Write data
                tl->outputfile->write((char*)(list->front().second->data()), sizeof(BYTE)* list->front().second->size());

                // Erase thread
                list->pop_front();

                // Delete count
                deleteCount++;

            }
            tl->listMutex.unlock();

            // Clean thread list
            auto lastdel = std::next(tl->threadList.begin(), deleteCount);
            tl->threadList.erase(tl->threadList.begin(), lastdel);
        }

        // End thread
        (*isRun) = false;
    }

void StartAlgoThread(std::pair<BYTE, std::vector<BYTE>*>* task, TaskList* tl){

        // Some code in future

        // All done
        task->first = 2;
    }
```

`Push` вызывается несколько раз.
Почему программа падает с ошибкой `SIGABRT` на `tl->threadList.erase(tl->threadList.begin(), lastdel);`
И как это исправить?

Comment: Алгоритм непонятен. В `StartAlgos` используется бесконечный цикл `while (list->size()){`. Команды выхода не вижу.

Comment: list->pop_front();

Comment: Цикл будет выполняться, пока лист не опустеет

Comment: Даже если у списка все элементы равны 2, то всё равно список закончится. А в цикле `while (list->front().first == 2)` даже нет проверки пустоты. `first() == end()` или `empty()`.

Comment: `while (!list->empty() && list->front().first == 2)` - порядок важен.

Comment: Спасибо - исправил, но все равно вылтает на tl->threadList.erase

Comment: ~thread()
    {
      if (joinable())
 std::terminate();
    }

Comment: Это где вылет в библиотеке thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил пока так:

```
while (list->size() && list->front().first == 2){

                // Write data
                tl->outputfile->write((char*)(list->front().second->data()), sizeof(BYTE)* list->front().second->size());

                // Erase thread
                delete list->front().second;
                list->pop_front();

                // Delete count
                deleteCount++;

            }
            tl->listMutex.unlock();

            // Clean thread list
            while (deleteCount--) {
                if (tl->threadList.front().joinable()) tl->threadList.front().join();
                tl->threadList.pop_front();
            }
```